# how to use If statement in aspx page with Bind/Eval method

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have written the following code:

```
<% if (Eval("ZoneName").ToString().ToLower().Equals("lahore"))
{%>
    <asp:HyperLink ID="hlShipmentDetail" runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
<%    
}
%>
```

But it produces this exception:

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(),
>   and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: As per the message, it's not the `if` statement which is the problem, but the `Eval`. You don't seem to be within a databound control, so where do you expect the "ZoneName" variable to be coming from, exactly? Perhaps tell us your actual intention and provide some more context about your variables, and maybe we can help you find the correct way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks @ADyson for your reply.  ZoneName" coming from database.

Comment: No, that doesn't cover it - you can't use database columns directly in an aspx page. Where in your C# code does it come from, I mean?

Comment: I am using repeater control.

Comment: Please show your code in the context of the Repeater then, and show how you databind your Repeater. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Move your program logic in a function - here's an example

Write on repeater on the aspx page :

`<%#GetShipmentDetail(Container.DataItem)%>`

and on code behind

```
protected string GetShipmentDetail(object oItem)
{
   var cZoneName = DataBinder.Eval(oItem, "ZoneName").ToString();

   if(cZoneName == "whatever")
      return "nothing";
   else
      return "something";

}
```

Comment: You're either going to be stuck using HTML in the returned string value (bad idea), or otherwise (e.g. when returning only the URL and handling the HTML wrapping in the webpage) you have no way of **not** providing a link (which is what the OP wants to do in their code snippet)

Comment: @Flater Do you have any other idea ? I think that the return of html is not so bad idea. Alternative in a repeater he can use a custom control to have all the logic that he needs, and place it on the repeater - but its something else